# register_post_meta show "Null"

Tags: custom-post-types

```
register_post_meta( 'job_listing', '_job_logo', array(
            'show_in_rest'      => true,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
        ) );
```

Is returning null, but there is data in phpMyAdmin.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, I assume the code is part of a `function`, if so please edit your question and add all code please.